# Raspberry hostname.local unable to resolve in MacBook Pro with Maverik

Tags: macos, ssh, localhost, raspberry-pi

I setup my raspberry with hostname but I cannot reach with SSH or WEB browser by my MacBookPro (running under maverick).
If i try by WIN 7 everything works!
On raspberry I setup avahi.

Running `avahi-browse --all`

```
+ eth0 IPv4 gmvpi Remote Disk Management local

+ eth0 IPv4 gmvpi SSH Remote Terminal local
+ eth0 IPv4 gmvpi _device-info._tcp local
+ eth0 IPv4 gmvpi Apple File Sharing local
+ eth0 IPv4 gmvpi [b8:27:eb:ea:80:9f] Workstation local
```

Running  `avahi-resolve --address 192.168.1.20`

```
192.168.1.20    gmvpi.local
```

so if i try `ssh pi@gmvpi.local`

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname gmvpi.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` and of course nor ping

if I address directly the IP 192.168.1.20 everyting works.

Any suggestion?

thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED!!

In my macbook pro 
system preference --> Network --> Advanced --> DNS I changed in domain from "Workgroup" to "local"
now i can ping Raspberry as pi@gmvpi.workgroup and

http://gmvpi.workgroup it's ok also!!
also in ftp as gmvpi.workgroup it's ok